# Automatic Version increment on Data-Tier Applications

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssdt, data-tier-application

In the project settings of a database project I can set the version number form my data-tier application, however setting this manually is a bit inefficient. I would like to automatically increment the build number, as with other VS projects. How can this be done ? At the same time I would like to see this version number in the generated dacpac file.

Answer (score 5):

I found this forum thread had an answer that worked well: [Automatic Version increment on Data-Tier Applications](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e0c93a55-d8bd-4a32-89d9-f46013fc1235/automatic-version-increment-on-datatier-applications?forum=ssdt)

Minimum steps are:

1. Create `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs` if it doesn't already exist, and make sure it's included in the project and contains at least this code: `using System.Reflection; [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]` Or however you want your version number to go.
2. Edit the `*.sqlproj` file in an outside editor (notepad etc) and add the following XML:

```xml
    <Target Name="SetDacVersionToAssemblyVersion" AfterTargets="CoreCompile">
        <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(IntermediateTargetFullFileName)">
            <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" PropertyName="IntermediateTargetAssembly" />
        </GetAssemblyIdentity>
        <PropertyGroup>
            <DacVersion>$(IntermediateTargetAssembly.Split(',')[1].Split('=')[1])
            </DacVersion>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <Message Text="DacVersion set to $(DacVersion)" Importance="high" />
    </Target>
```